# Triple nested dictionary comprehension?

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

Suppose I have a `pandas` `Series`, like this:

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(["hello go home bye bye", "you can't always get", "what you waaaaaaant", "apple banana carrot munch 123"])
```

I want to create a dictionary with individual characters as keys, and their frequencies as values. Creating these dictionaries for words in the past has been easy with the help of `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(word for row in s for word in row.lower().split())
```

However, I'm trying now to store individual characters and am having some issues with triple-nested dict comprehensions. Here's what I have:

```
c = Counter((letter for letter in word) for word for row in s for word in row.lower().split())
```

Which gives me a syntax error. How can I make the equivalent of the following `for` loop in one line?

```
d = {}
for row in s:
    for word in row.lower().split():
        for letter in word:
            d[letter] += 1
```

Comment: You appear to have a typo: `for word for row` shouldn't have **for word**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use

```
Counter([j for i in s for j in i])
Counter({'a': 16, ' ': 13, 'e': 6, 'o': 6, 'n': 5, 't': 5, 'y': 5, 'h': 4, 'l': 4, 'c': 3, 'b': 3, 'u': 3, 'w': 3, 'g': 2, 'm': 2, 'p': 2, 'r': 2, "'": 1, '1': 1, '3': 1, '2': 1, 's': 1})
```

to get the individual character count.

Comment: I see. For the individual characters, there's no need to run `split()` because words are irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

Just pass each word calling *.lower()* flattening the list of lists:

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(["hello go home bye bye", "you can't always get", "what you waaaaaaant", "apple banana carrot munch 123"])
from collections import Counter


print(Counter(word.lower() for row in s for word in row))
```

or chain with map:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

print(Counter(chain.from_iterable(map(str.lower, s))))
```

Both would give you:

```
Counter({'a': 16, ' ': 13, 'e': 6, 'o': 6, 'n': 5, 't': 5, 'y': 5, 'h': 4, 'l': 4, 'c': 3, 'b': 3, 'u': 3, 'w': 3, 'g': 2, 'm': 2, 'p': 2, 'r': 2, "'": 1, '1': 1, '3': 1, '2': 1, 's': 1})
```

You can also use *apply* or *s.str.lower()*

```
print(Counter(chain.from_iterable(s.apply(str.lower))))
print(Counter(chain.from_iterable(s.str.lower())))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using pandas:

```
n [6]: pd.Series(list(''.join(s))).value_counts()
Out[6]: 
a    16
     13
e     6
o     6
n     5
t     5
y     5
h     4
l     4
u     3
b     3
c     3
w     3
p     2
m     2
r     2
g     2
1     1
s     1
'     1
2     1
3     1
dtype: int64

In [7]: dict(pd.Series(list(''.join(s))).value_counts())
Out[7]: 
{' ': 13,
 "'": 1,
 '1': 1,
 '2': 1,
 '3': 1,
 'a': 16,
 'b': 3,
 'c': 3,
 'e': 6,
 'g': 2,
 'h': 4,
 'l': 4,
 'm': 2,
 'n': 5,
 'o': 6,
 'p': 2,
 'r': 2,
 's': 1,
 't': 5,
 'u': 3,
 'w': 3,
 'y': 5}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want this :

```
dict(zip([letter for row in s for word in row.lower().split() for letter in word], range(len([letter for row in s for word in row.lower().split() for letter in word]))))
```